# Customized read, split, and add to a list of objects from a large file

Tags: java, split, stream, skip, tolist

I am trying to figure out how I can customize read data from large file, the file is organized in this way :

> some text :  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
>   typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
>   dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
>   of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
>
> [line]
>
> id: 7xxxxx
>
> first_name: aaaaa
>
> last_name: aaaaaaaa
>
> -
>
> [line]
>
> id: 8xxxxx
>
> first_name: aaaaa
>
> last_name: aaaaaaaa
>
> nick_name: aaaaa
>
> nick_name: bbbbb
>
> -
>
> [line]
>
> id: 9xxxxx
>
> first_name: aaaaa
>
> last_name: aaaaaaaa
>
> -
>
> [line]
>
> id: 10xxxxx
>
> first_name: aaaaa
>
> last_name: aaaaaaaa
>
> nick_name: AAAAAA
>
> -
>
> [line]
>
> id: 11xxxxx
>
> first_name: aaaaa
>
> last_name: aaaaaaaa
>
> -
>
> [line]
>
> id: 12xxxxx
>
> first_name: aaaaa
>
> last_name: aaaaaaaa
>
> nick_name: qqqqqqqq
>
> nick_name: ssssssss
>
> nick_name: eeeeeeee
>
> nick_name: rrrrrrrr

```
public ArrayList<> getAllPersons() throws UtilisationException {
    List<String> allPersons = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = 
   new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/input.txt"))) {
        listDatas = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UtilisationException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}


public class Person {
    private String id;

    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;

    private List<String> nicknames;

    //getters setters & constructors 
}

public ArrayList<Person> convertedPersonsData() {
    List<Person> allConvertedPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    // How can i get all the data of persons && escaping the first one then added into  
    // allConvertedPersons 
    return allConvertedPersons;
 }
```

How can I get all the data of persons && escaping the first one then added into **allConvertedPersons** List?

Comment: if everything is just one line, you could have done `reader.lines().skip(1)` to be left with `Person` equivalent `String`s that could be deserialized to `List<Person>`

Comment: this is not a single line, the file is structured under the way above